# What is the proper way to check whether stdout was deleted

Tags: linux, c, stdout

I need to check from a running C program whether stdout was deleted.

By "deleted" I mean a situation when in `/proc/pid/fd` is written "deleted":

```
ll /proc/91495/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 ibse ibse  0 січ 31 00:49 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 ibse ibse  0 січ 31 00:49 ../
lrwx------ 1 ibse ibse 64 січ 31 00:49 0 -> '/dev/pts/5 (deleted)'
lrwx------ 1 ibse ibse 64 січ 31 00:50 1 -> '/dev/pts/5 (deleted)'
```

This can happen, for example, when the program's control terminal has been killed/closed.

Is there a way to check this without writing to stdout and checking the returned error?

I assumed that using `fstat(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf)` in this case would return an error,  but this is not the case.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15544990/8529284